# Possible issue when attempting to use an older gfortran 4.6 version compiler

Tags: fortran, gfortran

When a .mod file isn't found by the compiler as in...  "  set_mod.mod isn't a GFORTRAN module file.."   Is this a compiler or simply a remake issue of a new compiler onto a cluster??

Comment: Please use the fortran tag for all fortran-related questions.  Also use the more specific gfortran tag, rather than the generic gcc tag, when asking questions about gfortran.

Comment: You should really be recompiling almost everything when you change compilers/machines. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes, but more specifically when recompiling onto a large(somewhat loosely maintained) cluster of machines.

Answer (score -1):

The gfortran contributors try to maintain backwards compatibility of the module file format between different versions of the compiler.  Unfortunately, there are situations where compatibility cannot be maintained.  For example, the introduction of user-defined derived type IO caused an incompatibility, so the module file version number was bumped.  Best practice would be to use the same compiler major version number to compile all code (e.g., 4.6.2 and 4.8.3 should be ok).  If you jump to a new major version number, recompile everything.

Comment: The GCC version scheme has changed as of GCC 5. 4.6 and 4.8 are different major versions. But as of GCC 5, the first number determines the major version, not the second.

Comment: This is what I thought.   4.6 and 4.8 (or 4.4 for that matter, don't ask me how this version was still in use) seemed to have some significant differences